# Looking for a word starting with a voiced 's'

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling

Okay English Language, I come to you in an hour of despair. I had some late-night discussions yesterday about English pronunciation, which resulted in a bet, and the stakes are high. It basically boils down to the following question:

**Is there any word starting with an 's' that's being pronounced like a /z/?**

A *zero*, *zoo*, *zipper*, ... just with an s. I was pretty confident that there had to be, because there's an exception to almost every rule (like the rule that an 's' at the beginning of a word is pronounced voiceless ...).

Still, I haven't managed to find one so far. I already looked in [The Chaos](https://www.hep.wisc.edu/~jnb/charivarius.html), but no luck even there. I am out my wits and hope Stack Exchange can save me once again. Thanks a lot in advance to my noble hero/ine!

Comment: I downloaded the [CMU Pronouncing Dictionary](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/cgi-bin/cmudict) and literally the sole entry in the database that starts with the letter "s" but the phone /z/ is "Szilard", the surname of a Hungarian physicist. But a little research tells his name is properly pronounced /ˈsɪlɑːrd/, so I'm not sure what the CMU entry means. It is marked with a (1) in the database; maybe that's significant.

Comment: @DanBron: People often "mispronounce" names from Hungarian or from other Central European languages.

Comment: Trivia questions like this aren't on-topic here.

Comment: **Sion** is an older spelling of **Zion**. Both pronounced with initial /z/.

Comment: How do you pronounce the name of the the author of *The Cat in the Hat*?

Comment: I have to say, depending on the exact wording of your bet, I'd be fairly reluctant to accept any of the existing suggestions as proving your point.

Comment: This question does not appear to be about English language and usage within the scope defined in the help center.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on another site, https://puzzles.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found loads in the OED, but a lot of them aren't found in most smaller dictionaries.

> saal - /zɑːl/ "*rare* A large room or hall".
>
> Saarlander - /ˈzɑːlandə/ "An inhabitant of Saarland".
>
> Sachlichkeit -    /ˈzaxlɪxkʌɪt/ "Objectivism, realism".

However, here's a good one: **seidel** - https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/seidel - /ˈzʌɪd(ə)l/ - "A beer mug or glass" (Oxford Dictionaries online).

M-W gives an alternative pronunciation with "s", but Oxford doesn't.

Another found in ODO is **Sonderweg** - https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sonderweg - /ˈzɒndəvɛɡ/ - "distinct course of development". (Not found in M-W).

Comment: All German words.

Comment: Great answer! If there is, I'd prefer a 'non-foreign' word, but otherwise, this will be my answer. Thanks already rjpond!

Comment: Yes... Arguably, the trouble is that once a foreign word becomes sufficiently naturalised as to be indisputably English, some people start pronouncing it with "s-", though Oxford is more conservative on this point than M-W.

Comment: Indeed, @rjpond -- for example sauerkraut.

Comment: @rjpond  Or else they start spelling it with a "z".

Answer (score 7):

[*'Sblood*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/sblood) /zblʌd/. This is not in my opinion a very satisfactory answer, since it's an archaic interjection, but it is a native "word". It originated as a contraction of "God's blood". (I guess someone could also quibble that it technically doesn't start with an "s", it starts with an apostrophe.)

Even though most English words don't start with consonant clusters like /zbl/ (it's something that marks this word as not part of basic English vocabulary) I can't really imagine it being naturalized to anything else. A sequence like /sbl/ would be even more unnatural in English, because of the clash between the voiceless phoneme /s/ and the voiced phoneme /b/, and I would expect it to be assimilated to /spl/. But would anyone pronounce "'sblood" as "splud"? I think it's not very likely.

There are a few words from Italian used in English that also have consonant clusters starting with /z/, spelled "s", followed by a voiced plosive like this; the most commonly encountered is probably *[sgraffito](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sgraffito)* (which apparently some people do pronounce as "skraffito").

Comment: Good thinking!  I think there are some similar ones - *'sdeath*, for instance ( https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sdeath ).

Comment: *Zounds* started out this way, as "God's wounds", and was occasionally spelled with an S. I don't know that it would be accepted for a bet today, though; English really seems to resist initial-S pronounced /z/, preferring to regularize either the pronunciation or the spelling.